# How to add quantity if item already exist

Tags: java, android

I would like to check whether a record exists or not.If exist , i want to add the quantity.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code = etCode.getText().toString();
                String product = etProduct.getText().toString();
                String qty = etQty.getText().toString();
                try {
                    if (isExist(code)) {
                        rQty = Integer.parseInt(rQty + etQty.getText().toString());
                    } else {
                        myDB.addData(code, product, Integer.parseInt(qty));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
 public boolean isExist(String code) {
        boolean result;
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT QTY FROM users_data WHERE CODE " + code + "'", null);
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0 ){
                while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    rQty = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("QTY"));
                }
                result = true;
            }else {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the code.if insert the same code of item , the data become duplicate and it not add the quantity for the same code.Please help me to solve this problem .

Comment: `if(itemExist) then update ++quantity  else insert item` .

Comment: That problem is your query is malformed . It should be as `SELECT QTY FROM users_data WHERE CODE = ' " + code + " '"` . You have missed `=`. Also please look into logs and debug the code before posting question here .Its for your own skills gains.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors and bugs in your code. One problem is this code

```
 rQty = Integer.parseInt(rQty + etQty.getText().toString());
```

It won't add qQty with input quantity. because here strings concatenated. 
You have to use

```
 rQty += Integer.parseInt (qty);
```

Second one is your sqlite query is not right and it is incomplete
so change

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT QTY FROM users_data WHERE CODE " + code + "'", null);
```

to

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT QTY FROM users_data WHERE CODE = '" + code + "'", null);
```

Try below code

```
  btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String code = etCode.getText().toString();
            String product = etProduct.getText().toString();
            String qty = etQty.getText().toString();
            try {
                if (isExist(code)) {
                    rQty += Integer.parseInt (qty);
                } else {
                    myDB.addData(code, product, Integer.parseInt(qty));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
public boolean isExist(String code) {
    boolean result;
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT QTY FROM users_data WHERE CODE = '" + code + "'", null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0 ){
            while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                rQty = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("QTY"));
            }
            result = true;
        }else {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: At Least point out the errors in Op's code . so that he/she can learn from it.